# Card's ant design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I need to make the image appear in the full width of the ant design card

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import uno from '../images/dualComida.jpg'
import {
    Button,
    Space,
    Typography,
    Input,
    Select,
    message,
    Row,
    
    Divider,
    Form,
    Checkbox,
    Grid,
    Radio,
    Modal,
    Card
  } from "antd";
  import { SketchOutlined , SmileOutlined, SafetyCertificateOutlined, WomanOutlined, UserOutlined, LockOutlined, InfoCircleOutlined, IdcardOutlined, ClockCircleOutlined, DollarOutlined  } from "@ant-design/icons";

import Item from 'antd/lib/list/Item';
import mvp from '../images/dualComida.jpg'
import delivery from '../desing/delivery.svg'
import '../desing/desing.css'
const { Title, Text } = Typography;

function CardsComida({setModal2Open}) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
   // Wait for 3 seconds
   setTimeout(() => {
     setIsLoading(false);
    
   }, 8000);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div  className='homeContainer'  >
   
    
   
    
    <div  >
    
     <Card className='card' onClick={() => setModal2Open(true)} loading={isLoading} cover={<img alt="example" src={mvp}  loading={isLoading} hoverable/>}
  >

    <Title level={3} >Nombre de la comida</Title>
    
    <Text> Precio </Text>
    <ClockCircleOutlined />
      <Text>
      <img width='3%' src={delivery}></img> 15-20min 
    
      </Text>
    
      <Text>
         Envio Gratis
      </Text>
      <DollarOutlined />
    
     </Card>
    </div>    
    </div>
  )
}

export default CardsComida;
```

I tried to use a Style, but it didn't work, I tried several ways.
I want it to look like a rappi card, as it appears in the image[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsjTz.png)

ant design does not give information to solve it.
so far the image is only placed in a corner in small size

Answer (score 0):

Use grids, and css it with border-shadow

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your homeContainer css probably here you put css padding or margin. or check your application body style

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, Typography } from "antd";
import { ClockCircleOutlined, DollarOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
const { Title, Text } = Typography;
import "./styles.css";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Card
      hoverable
      style={{
        width: 240,
      }}
      cover={
        <img
          alt="example"
          src="https://99grid.com/cdn/shop/products/WhatsAppImage2022-06-23at7.47.46PM_720x.jpg?v=1656143187"
        />
      }
    >
      <Title level={3}>Nombre de la comida</Title>

      <Text> Precio </Text>
      <ClockCircleOutlined />
      <Text> 15-20min </Text>

      <Text>Envio Gratis</Text>
      <DollarOutlined />
    </Card>
  );
}
```

You can see live demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/laughing-carlos-8929lj)